# Accessing a php service from within a standard HTML page

Tags: php, web-services

I have a number of services written in PHP that an app I've been working on happily communicates with. The services so return a JSON block of data.

I'm trying to get a web page to access the web services, but I'm getting nothing back. Chances are it's down to the services having parameters set in the body, but I'm not able to verify this.

The hosting I'm using won't allow me to install additional libraries, so I'm probably going to be restricted to using curl.

My question is how do I actually access the service. I'm guessing I'll need something akin to

```
 <?php
    // Set up curl
    // Call service
    // Decode returned JSON string
  ?>
```

Is this correct or will I need to do something a bit differently?

Comment: You should determine **why** the web pages cannot access your PHP service. Hint: It's probably CORS related if the web pages are using JavaScript

Comment: No JS at all on the page - I took that out in case it was causing the issue